# Loop inside a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is My console.log]

The result turns out to be console 2 students first, and then all the data doubled

What I want is to Have

```
student 1 {
  data:H3FX.., data:I3ui.., data:RdYS.., ....
}

student 2 { 
  data:H3FX.., data:I3ui.., data:RdYS.., ....
}
```

I'm getting confused by react rendering and syntax so many times.

```
this.state.allStudent.map(student => {
      console.log('student:'+student.id);
      studentid = student.id
      db.doc(this.props.location.state.userCourse).collection('assignment').get().then( snapshot =>{
          snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
            db.doc(this.props.location.state.userCourse).collection('assignment').doc(doc.id).collection('student').get().then(query=>{
              query.forEach(querysnapshot=>{
                if(querysnapshot.data().studentid == student.id){
                  console.log('data:'+doc.id)
                }
              })
            })
          })
      })
    })`
```

Answer (score 0):

`.map` does not wait for each promise to be fulfilled so before any of the database calls have had any chance to be completed, the two first console logs are processed and then each subsequent log are the promises being resolved.

Now as for why the logs are doubled it could either be because of some issue on the way you're fetching your data or maybe [because of this.](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/)